# How to display both sum and count

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Using crossfilter api i have created one dimension and one group . i want to display count of each group and sum of each group in dc composite chart . But on both left and right y axis it is displaying sum only .

```
 var data = [
             {"class" : 'class I' , "donation": 400},
             {"class" : 'Class II' , "donation" : 500}];
 var donationCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
 var classDim = donationCrossfilter.dimension(function(d){ return d.class});
 var classGrp = classDim.group();
 var compositechart = dc.compositeChart("#compositechart");
 compositechart
   .x(d3.scaleBand())
   .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
   .margins({top:5 , right:60 , left : 60 , bottom:20})
   .elasticY(true)
   .group(classGrp)
   .dimension(classDim)
   .rightY(d3.scaleLinear())
   .xAxis().tickSize(0);
 compositechart.compose(
         [
          dc.lineChart(compositechart)
            .group(classGrp)
            .valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value} ),
          dc.barChart(compositechart)
            .group(classGrp.reduceSum(function(d){ return d.donation}))
            .valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value})
            .useRightYAxis(true)
          ]);

 compositechart.render();
```

On left y axis it should show count of each class that is 1 ,1  and on right y axis it should should sum of each class donation that is 400 , 500

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat surprising when learning crossfilter: it seems like it should use the functional style of programming, but the API is actually imperative.

So when you select `reduceCount` or `reduceSum`, that actually *changes the existing group object* to use that reduction, and returns the same object.

In your example, sum replaces count, and both child charts display the sum.

To get two groups, one counting and one summing, do:

```
var classGrpCount = classDim.group().reduceCount();
var classGrpSum = classDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.donation});
//...
compositechart.compose(
         [
          dc.lineChart(compositechart)
            .group(classGrpCount)
            .valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value} ),
          dc.barChart(compositechart)
            .group(classGrpSum)
            .valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value})
            .useRightYAxis(true)
          ]);
```

I think this style was chosen in the name of efficiency. Since each group will continue to exist and track changes to the selection, you wouldn't want these functions to create new groups.